# Groovy / Java method for converting nested List String representation back to List

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, groovy

I need to convert a String representation of a nested List back to a nested List (of Strings) in Groovy / Java, e.g.

```
String myString = "[[one, two], [three, four]]"
List myList = isThereAnyMethodForThis(myString)
```

I know that there's the Groovy .split method for splitting Strings by comma for example and that I could use regular expressions to identify nested Lists between [ and ], but I just want to know if there's an existing method that can do this or if I have to write this code myself.

I guess the easiest thing would be a List constructor that takes the String representation as an argument, but I haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Groovy, if your strings are delimited as such, you can do this:

```
String myString = "[['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']]"
List myList = Eval.me(myString)
```

However, if they are not delimited like in your example, I think you need to start playing with the shell and a custom binding...

```
class StringToList extends Binding {
  def getVariable( String name ) {
    name
  }
  def toList( String list ) {
    new GroovyShell( this ).evaluate( list )
  }
}

String myString = "[[one, two], [three, four]]"
List myList = new StringToList().toList( myString )
```

#### Edit to explain things

The [Binding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) in Groovy *"Represents the variable bindings of a script which can be altered from outside the script object or created outside of a script and passed into it."*

So here, we create a custom binding which returns the name of the variable when a variable is requested (think of it as setting the default value of any variable to the name of that variable).

We set this as being the Binding that the [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) will use for evaluating variables, and then run the String representing our list through the Shell.

Each time the Shell encounters `one`, `two`, etc., it assumes it is a variable name, and goes looking for the value of that variable in the Binding.  The binding simply returns the name of the variable, and that gets put into our list

#### Another edit...  I found a shorter way

You can use Maps as Binding objects in Groovy, and you can use a `withDefault` closure to Maps so that when a key is missing, the result of this closure is returned as a default value for that key.  [An example can be found here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/07/groovy-goodness-map-with-default-values.html)

This means, we can cut the code down to:

```
String myString = "[[one, two], [three, four]]"
Map bindingMap = [:].withDefault { it }
List myList = new GroovyShell( bindingMap as Binding ).evaluate( myString )
```

As you can see, the Map (thanks to `withDefault`) returns the key that was passed to it if it is missing from the Map.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how & why this Binding thing works, but it works... Thank you for this short & obviously elegant solution!

Comment: Added a bit more explanation...hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would parse this String manually. Each time you see a '[' create a new List, each time you see a ',' add an element to the list and each time you see a ']' return.

With a recursive method.

```
public int parseListString(String listString, int currentOffset, List list){
    while(currentOffset < listString.length()){
        if(listString.startsWith("[", currentOffset)){
            //If there is a [ we need a new List
            List newList = new ArrayList();
            currentOffset  = parseListString(listString, currentOffset+1, newList);
            list.add(newList);
        }else if(listString.startsWith("]", currentOffset){
            //If it's a ], then the list is ended
            return currentOffset+1;
        }else{
            //Here we have a string, parse it until next ',' or ']'
            int nextOffset = Math.min(listString.indexOf(',', currentOffset), listString.indexOf(']', currentOffset));
            String theString = listString.substring(int currentOffset, int nextOffset);
            list.add(theString);

            //increment currentOffset
            currentOffset = nextOffset;
        }
    }
    return currentOffset;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to what I would have tried, but tim_yates solution seems even simpler - although I don't know which one performs better, but I guess it doesn't make a difference with today's hardware.